# Wrong result by FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction

Slight background: I am trying to find the coexistence reduced pressure ($p_r$) of a Van der Waals fluid at a reduced temperature of 0.85, this requires finding the solution to the following system of equations where $p_r$ is the only control variable:

1. $p_r = -(3/v_r^2) + (8 * 0.85)/(-1 + 3 v_r)$

Of course, the above equation is a cubic in vr, and you get three positive roots for certain values of $0<pr<1$. I label the smallest of these roots $v_{r,1}$ up 
 to $v_{r,3}$. Then, the second equation to be satisfied is the following integral equation:

2. $\int_{v_{r,1}}^{v_{r,3}} \left[-(3/v_r^2) + \frac{(8 * 0.85)}{(-1 + 3 v_r)}\right] dv_r = p_r(v_{r,3}-v_{r,1})$

The integral turns out to have an analytical solution, so to make things easier, I write:

$\int_{v_{r,1}}^{v_{r,3}} \left[-(3/v_r^2) + \frac{(8 * 0.85)}{(-1 + 3 v_r)}\right] dv_r=\frac{3}{v_{r,3}} - \frac{3}{v_{r,1}}  + \frac{8*0.85}{3}\, \, Log[\frac{-1 + 3 v_{r,3}}{-1 + 3 v_{r,1}}]$

To do that on Mathematica, I introduce the following module:

```
f[pr_, tr_] := Module[{vr1, vr2, vr3},
  sol = Sort[vr /. NSolve[pr == -(3/vr^2) + (8*tr)/(-1 + 3 vr), vr]];
  vr1 = sol[[1]]; vr2 = sol[[2]]; vr3 = sol[[3]];
  Re[(3/vr + 8/3 tr Log[-1 + 3 vr] /. 
      vr -> vr3) - (3/vr + 8/3 tr Log[-1 + 3 vr] /. vr -> vr1) - 
    pr*(vr3 - vr1) ]
  ]
```

Then I plot `f[pr,0.85]` to find a graphical solution:

Plot[f[pr, 0.85], {pr, 0.4, 0.55}]

[image]

So it is clear that the solution is pr = 0.505 (also independently checked).

However, watch what happens when I use FindRoot:

```
FindRoot[f[pr, 0.85], {pr, 0.4, 0.1, 0.6}, Method -> "Newton"]
```

I get:

```
{pr -> 0.530736}
```

I've tried changing the Method and the search intervals to no avail.

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: The difference is that Plot holds it's first argument, while FindRoot does not. The simplest solution is to add an argument restriction, i.e., `f[pr_?NumericQ, tr_] := Module[...]`.

Comment: Guess what? It works! Thank you. Why did that happen though?

Comment: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot) evaluates `f[pr, .8]` where `pr` is just a symbol, it is not a number. Then, it replaces `pr` with a number. However, the order of the roots when `pr` is a symbol differs from the order of the roots when `pr` is a number. Here is a function that just solves your first equation:

```
g[pr_, tr_] := Sort[vr/.NSolve[pr==-(3/vr^2)+(8*tr)/(-1+3 vr),vr]];
```

Now, let's evaluate `g` with a symbolic `pr`:

```
g[pr, .85] //Short
```

> {-((0.0222222 (-34.-<<1>>))/pr)+((<<21>> -<<1>>) <<1>>)/(pr <<1>>^<<1>>)-((<<1>>) <<1>>)/pr,<<1>>,<<1>>}

It's rather complicated, so I truncated the output. Now compare substituting a value for `pr` into the above expression versus just evaluating `g` with a numeric `pr`:

```
g[pr, .85] /. pr -> .5 //Chop
g[.5, .85]
```

> {1.13734, 0.553756, 3.17557}
>
> {0.553756, 1.13734, 3.17557}

The order is different. This is why your [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot) code doesn't work. Defining `f` so that it doesn't evaluate for symbolic `pr` fixes your problem:

```
Clear[f]
f[pr_?NumericQ, tr_] := Module[{vr1, vr2, vr3},
    sol = Sort[vr /. NSolve[pr == -(3/vr^2) + (8*tr)/(-1 + 3 vr), vr]];
    vr1 = sol[[1]]; vr2 = sol[[2]]; vr3 = sol[[3]];
    Re[
        (3/vr + 8/3 tr Log[-1 + 3 vr] /. vr -> vr3) - 
        (3/vr + 8/3 tr Log[-1 + 3 vr] /. vr -> vr1) - 
        pr*(vr3 - vr1)
    ]
]
FindRoot[f[pr, .85], {pr, .5}]
```

> {pr -> 0.504492}

Another possibility is to use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) with the [`Cubics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cubics)->[`False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/False) option instead of [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve). This is because [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) will return [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) objects, and Mathematica knows how to sort [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) objects even for symbolic arguments:

```
Clear[f]
f[pr_, tr_] := Module[{vr1, vr2, vr3},
    sol = vr /. Quiet @ Solve[pr == -(3/vr^2) + (8*tr)/(-1 + 3 vr), vr, Cubics->False];
    vr1 = sol[[1]]; vr2 = sol[[2]]; vr3 = sol[[3]];
    Re[
        (3/vr + 8/3 tr Log[-1 + 3 vr] /. vr -> vr3) - 
        (3/vr + 8/3 tr Log[-1 + 3 vr] /. vr -> vr1) - 
        pr*(vr3 - vr1)
    ]
]
FindRoot[f[pr, .85], {pr, .5}]
```

> {pr -> 0.504492}

*(the [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet) is to avoid messages related to using exact methods with inexact coefficients)*

Let's examine the output of [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve):

```
Solve[pr == -(3/vr^2) + (8*tr)/(-1 + 3 vr), vr, Cubics->False]
```

> {{vr -> Root[-3 + 9 #1 + (-pr - 8 tr) #1^2 + 3 pr #1^3 &, 1]}, {vr -> 
>      Root[-3 + 9 #1 + (-pr - 8 tr) #1^2 + 3 pr #1^3 &, 2]}, {vr -> 
>      Root[-3 + 9 #1 + (-pr - 8 tr) #1^2 + 3 pr #1^3 &, 3]}}

Notice how each solution is just a [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) object with an index. By default, the indices correspond to roots with increasing real part. This is what you were trying to achieve with your [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort), so it isn't necessary in the above code.